# Expected value of a biased coin

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, bayes-theorem

I came across this question of finding expected value of p given Head showed up in last toss of coin. Here p is probability of a biased coin showing H and p is given as uniformly distributed.

Comment: $\displaystyle \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1 p^2 \, dp }{\displaystyle \int_0^1 p \, dp}$ ?

Comment: Are you referring to the recent result by Miller and Sanjuro?  That concerned the expected probability under the given condition.  A good summary can be found, e.g., here: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/did-previous-researchers-fail-to-detect-the-hot-hand-simply-because-of-a-statist